# Are there any situations in which you would use NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE on a Unicode database?

Tags: oracle, unicode, character-encoding

Having a Unicode (multi-byte charset) Oracle database with NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE seems like a disaster waiting to happen. Field validation in most applications only check the number of characters is within bounds, not the byte sequence length in the database’s default character encoding scheme! If you've got a Unicode database, is there ever a good reason to use NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE rather than CHAR?

Comment: Byte semantics is a disaster; got bit by that last week. But CHAR semantics only solves so much. "Independently of the maximum length in characters, the length of VARCHAR2 data cannot exceed 4000 **bytes**." (Emphasis added) For sufficiently large strings you may hit the maximum space allowed before hitting the size limit specified on the column. Quoted from: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i45694

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just legacy, I think. There are plenty of old applications that have always worked on bytes and may get confused if this changes. Anything where byte strings and indexes go off to an external app/language that works in bytes is going to go wrong in weird and unpredictable ways if the indexes are redefined underneath it.

I would not use byte semantics for a new application and I agree that it's not a good default. But then hopefully you're using NVARCHAR, which avoids the issue (since it's always character-based).

Comment: Specifically, I know that Crystal Management Server on Oracle (for configuration database) requires NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE. It throws a fit until you get to SP2. The work around is a logon trigger applied to the crystal user.